# mathtime mt11p mtpro2 into texlive

Tags: fonts, texlive, mtpro

Dear TeXperts:  someone sent me some latex files that require mtgub fonts.

(Previous Fixing Attempts: I had hoped that by switching to the ubuntu 13.10 texlive distribution with texlive-extra-fonts (in contrast to my earlier use of a direct install), the fonts would magically appear.  alas, they did not.)

mtgub seems to be a mathtime font in ctan package mt11p, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mt11p .  mt11p on ctan maximizes confusion by referring to being a package that uses mathtime fonts as distributed by Y&Y, but that have no connection with the mathtime package commissioned by Y&Y.  not kidding.

eventually, the mt11p package also refers to PCTeX's MathTime Pro fonts.   PCTeX has a "lite" free version (great!) as well as a pro version, but the installation instructions only for tetex, which has been out of date since 2006.  nowadays, we have texlive.  PCTeX has no font installation instructions for texlive.

so, I need to find out (a) exactly what files I need (mtplite.zip from pctex?) and (b) how to install them.  help?

Comment: The MathTimePro Lite fonts are indeed available for free, but their license is not free in a sense that makes TeX Live able to include them. Actually they are not on CTAN, but must be downloaded from PCTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I recommend uninstalling Ubuntu's tex packages since have two installations of tex will only confuse things. (It is possible to keep both if you want to but you then need to be much more careful about what you are doing.)

I'm going to assume you are working with the directly installed distribution which I assume is TeX Live 2013.

I'm not familiar with these particular fonts so if anything doesn't quite fit or work, let me know.

You need to decide where to install the fonts. There are two reasonable options. The first is in your personal texmf tree. These will be available only to your user and there are some disadvantages in terms of updates to TeX Live. The second option is to install them into your local texmf tree. I would recommend this option.

If the following directories do not exist, create them [you may need to do this with sudo if you ignored the advice not to install TeX Live as root]:

1. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/pctex/mt11p` [pctex based on help from egreg - see comments]

   - copy the .pfb files you downloaded from PCTeX here
2. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/afm/pctex/mt11p`

   - copy the .afm files you downloaded from PCTeX here
3. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/pctex/mt11p`

   - copy the .tfm files from the tfm directory from the archive you downloaded from CTAN here
4. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/vf/pctex/mt11p`

   - copy the .vf files from the vf directory from the archive you downloaded from CTAN here
5. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/mt11p`

   - copy the .map file from the archive you downloaded from CTAN here
6. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/mt11p`

   - run latex on the .ins file from the archive you downloaded from CTAN; copy the resulting .sty file here
7. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/fonts/mt11p`

   - run latex on the .dtx file from the archive you downloaded from CTAN; copy the resulting documentation here
8. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/source/fonts/mt11p`

   - copy the source files you downloaded from CTAN and which don't go elsewhere (e.g. .dtx, .ins) here - this is entirely optional and is just for future reference; you can skip this step completely if you like

Now update TeX's file database by running `mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.

Now install the fonts for use by TeX by running `updmap-sys --enable Map mt11p.map`.

You should now be able to use the fonts. Note that generating the documentation might fail if the documentation requires the fonts and the fonts are not yet installed. This won't stop the installation working but if you want the documentation, you can either just install the ready-made .pdf you downloaded as part of the CTAN archive or you can rerun latex on the .dtx file after installing the fonts.

Comment: Maybe `pctex` instead of `public`?

Comment: Would that be right? I couldn't figure out what it should be for what are basically y&y fonts. I thought that fontname included information about directories for vendors but when I checked (quickly, I admit), I couldn't find anything that looked relevant. And I may be mistaken in any case.

Comment: My MTPro2 fonts (Lite version) are in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/<...>/pctex/mtpro2/` where `<...>` stands for `tfm` or `type1` (there are no `.vf` files in the distribution). It's an arbitrary decision, maybe, but `public` is not the correct choice. They'll be found nonetheless.

Comment: That's a good enough reason. I know public was wrong - I just couldn't figure out what was right and I knew public would work. (And public seemed better than an incorrect vendor, if that makes sense, since there is already a bunch of stuff in public that really has a vendor of some kind.) Anyway, thanks. I'll update the instructions.

Comment: @egreg I eventually found what I was looking for but I think pctex is more correct than yandy, perhaps, since although the fonts are originally from y&y, fontname's guidelines require assigning fonts to final rather than original vendors on the grounds that vendors frequently modify them. (So an ITC font distributed by Adobe starts with a p-- and goes under adobe/.) Does that seem right in this case?

Comment: I think so. Since PCTeX is the final vendor…